# Reformat google sheet info using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table in Google Sheets that I need to reformat. It looks like this:

[image: Input Table]

I want to reformat it in order to get a table with two columns: Position and Value. The column "position" should merge the information of the column and row name of the original table; and the column "Value" should have its value. For example, if I have "Bread1" as a value for column A and row 1, I want "A1" for the column Position and "Bread1" for the column Value. See the images for a better explanation.

[image: Desired Output]

The data is available at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BNmjLAMlE67ALM0h5qzReMjfLQljoYlw60pIc62O5w4/edit?usp=sharing

So far, I have tried this code to duplicate the table (only) and it did not work.

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("FoodMap");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("KeepTrying");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(3,1,1,10);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code for your desired output.

Please note that the FoodMap sheet is slightly changed and range may differ from your original sheet.

### Code:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("FoodMap");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("KeepTrying");

  // get values on the foodMap sheet
  var values = copySheet.getRange(2, 2, copySheet.getLastRow() - 1, copySheet.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues(); //Values is obtain starting from row 2 column 2
  // get column header
  var col_header = copySheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, copySheet.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();
  // get row index
  var row_index = copySheet.getRange(2, 1, copySheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

  //processing of data
  var newvValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row_index.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < col_header[0].length; j++) {
      newvValues.push([row_index[i] + col_header[0][j], values[i][j]])
    }
  }
    pasteSheet.getRange(2,1,newvValues.length,newvValues[0].length).setValues(newvValues) //setting the values to KeepTrying tab
}
```

### Custom Formula Script:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("FoodMap");

  // get values on the foodMap sheet
  var values = copySheet.getRange(2, 2, copySheet.getLastRow() - 1, copySheet.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues(); //Values is obtain starting from row 2 column 2
  // get column header
  var col_header = copySheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, copySheet.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();
  // get row index
  var row_index = copySheet.getRange(2, 1, copySheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

  //processing of data
  var newvValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row_index.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < col_header[0].length; j++) {
      newvValues.push([row_index[i] + col_header[0][j], values[i][j]])
    }
  }
  return newvValues;
}
```

### FoodMap sheet:

[image]

### KeepTrying sheet(output):

[image]

### References:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#methods

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! it works perfectly!!! I have only one question left.
I could run it perfectly from the apps script with the _Run_ button since it asked me for permissions. Is there a way to run it calling the function `=copyInfo()` from the KeepTrying sheet? When I try to do it, it says : _Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues_ ... Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad that was useful. I believe you are looking for a custom formula. I've revised my previous response to add a custom formula script. If you have any further questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you @George ! This is exactly what I was looking for! I am sorry I was not clear in the post, I actually did not know you need different code for "run it in app" and "custom formula" ways of running the function, until now since I am a newbie in Apps Script. This will be the first step in my pipeline so I will continue to explore Apps Script thanks to you! Have a great day!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer

Comment: I just did! I did not know about the button!